# how to distinguish an operation in spark is a transformation or an action?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm learning spark recently and confused about the transformation and action operation. I read the spark document and some books about spark, and I know action will cause a spark job to be executed in the cluster while transformation will not. But the operations of rdd listed in spark's api doc are not stated whether it is a transformation or an action operation.

For example, reduce is an action, on the other hand reduceByKey is a transformation! Why could this be.

Comment: While Spark Transformation builds execution plan, Action immediately immediately triggers computation to return an output result by running that plan. Find [more info from here](https://medium.com/data-engineering-lab/navigating-the-spark-transformations-vs-actions-in-apache-spark-30f7fd8726d9).

Answer (score 14):

You can tell by looking at the return type. An action will return a non-RDD type (your stored value types usually), whereas a transformation will return an `RDD[Type]` as it is still just a representation of your computation.

Comment: Would you kindly complement  Dataframe or Dataset?