# How to distinguish actions from transformations in pyspark methods

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In spark for java, we can identify whether an operation on RDD is whether an transformation or action thorough method signature. If method returns an RDD then it would mostly be an transformation, otherwise an action.

How can this distinction be made in py-spark python API for spark?

Comment: Hope this helps. [One of the earlier posts][1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371993/how-to-distinguish-a-operation-in-spark-is-a-transformation-or-a-action